# Watir Checkbox Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, checkbox, rspec, watir

On the following [page](http://www.bod.de/premium-services/anfrage.html)I want to test and check all checkboxes.
But I always get an error after the first checkbox test.

My Code:

```
checkLArr = Array["L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7"]
x = 0
for i in 0 .. 7 do
    checkbox = @browser.div(:class => 'check-handler')
    if checkbox.should exist and checkbox.input(:id => "#{checkLArr[x]}").should exist
       puts "GEIL jetzt wird geklickt"
       puts checkLArr[x]
       checkbox.click
       x += 1
    else
       puts "Geht nicht"
    end
 end
```

Error Message:

```
expected #<Watir::Input:0x..faa4dba70 located=false selector={:id=>"L2", :tag_name=>"input"}> to exist
./lektorat_anfrage.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
./lektorat_anfrage.rb:41:in `each'
./lektorat_anfrage.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The main problem is with the lines:

```
checkbox = @browser.div(:class => 'check-handler')
checkbox.input(:id => "#{checkLArr[x]}").should exist
```

`checkbox` is the first div on the page with class 'check-handler'. On the actual page, each checkbox is in its own 'check-handler' div. The 'L2', 'L3', etc. checkboxes are not in the first div and therefore throw the exception.

In other words, the code is looking for a structure like:

```
<div class="check-handler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="L1" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="L2" />
</div>
```

When the HTML is actually like:

```
<div class="check-handler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="L1" />
</div>
<div class="check-handler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="L2" />
</div>
```

**Solution**

From the code, it looks like you want to check the div element that contains the particular checkbox. Given that the checkbox has a unique ID, it will be easier to find the checkbox and then navigate up the DOM to the parent div:

```
browser.checkbox(:id => "#{checkLArr[x]}").parent.click
```

I would suggest not using a for loop as it increases the chance of mistake (eg the checkLArr has one too few elements). As well, using assertions in the if statement seems rather strange. I would suggest:

```
checkLArr = Array["L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7"]
checkLArr.each do |id|
  input = browser.checkbox(:id => id)
  if input.exists?
    puts "GEIL jetzt wird geklickt"
    puts id
    input.parent.click
  else
    puts "Geht nicht"
  end
end
```